# Core Foundation and Cocoa Touch underscore naming convention (1 or 2 underscores?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, core-foundation

I'm trying to understand the Core Foundation and Cocoa Touch systems at a deeper level by playing with Instruments and just exploring.

What is the underscore naming convention for Core Foundation (CF) and Cocoa Touch (UI)?

For example, here is the runtime error I got with one of my apps. Why are some CF methods prefixed with 2 underscores `(__CFRunLoopDoSources0,__CFRunLoopRun)` while others are not `(CFRunLoopRunSpecific, CFRunLoopRunInMode)`? Same with UI methods. Why are some prefixed with 1 underscore `(  _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent,_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue)` while others are not `(UIApplicationMain)`?

```
2014-10-30 11:02:54.929 Scratchpad3[1822:204482] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x790806f0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'PageViewController''
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0362d946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x032b6a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   UIKit                               0x022a70fc -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] + 0
    3   Scratchpad3                         0x00070fcf -[Analytics2ViewController viewDidLoad] + 383
    4   UIKit                               0x01de52a4 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 771
    5   UIKit                               0x01de5595 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    6   Scratchpad3                         0x00060d75 -[IIViewDeckController setCenterController:] + 3429
    7   Scratchpad3                         0x0007087a -[SettingsViewController analytics2Clicked:] + 170
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x032cc7cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    9   UIKit                               0x01c8f23d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    10  UIKit                               0x01c8f1cf -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    11  UIKit                               0x01dc2e86 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
    12  UIKit                               0x01dc32a3 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
    13  UIKit                               0x01dc250d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
    14  UIKit                               0x01cdf60a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
    15  UIKit                               0x01ce00e5 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791
    16  UIKit                               0x01ca5549 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    17  UIKit                               0x01cb537e _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
    18  UIKit                               0x01c89b19 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x035511df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x03546ced __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x03546248 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x03545bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x035459fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x054cb24f GSEventRunModal + 192
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x054cb08c GSEventRun + 104
    26  UIKit                               0x01c8d8b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    27  Scratchpad3                         0x00071d5d main + 141
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x040f3ac9 start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Underscores are typically used to denote internal behaviour. It's basically their way of saying "Yo, don't try to reference this. It's weird and different, so that should scare you off."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple says
*Avoid the use of the underscore character as a prefix meaning private in method names (using an
underscore character as a prefix for an instance variable name is allowed). Apple reserves the use of this
convention. Use by third parties could result in name-space collisions; they might unwittingly override an
existing private method with one of their own, with disastrous consequences.*

Also

*In most cases, private method names generally follow the same rules as public method names. However, a
common convention is to give private methods a prefix so it is easy to distinguish them from public methods.
Even with this convention, the names given to private methods can cause a peculiar type of problem. When
you design a subclass of a Cocoa framework class, you cannot know if your private methods unintentionally
override private framework methods that are identically named.
Names of most private methods in the Cocoa frameworks have an underscore prefix (for example, _fooData
) to mark them as private. From this fact follow two recommendations.

Don’t use the underscore character as a prefix for your private methods. Apple reserves this convention.

If you are subclassing a large Cocoa framework class (such as NSView or UIView) and you want to be
absolutely sure that your private methods have names different from those in the superclass, you can add
your own prefix to your private methods. The prefix should be as unique as possible, perhaps one based
on your company or project and of the form "XX_". So if your project is called Byte Flogger, the prefix
might be BF_addObject:
Although the advice to give private method names a prefix might seem to contradict the earlier claim that
methods exist in the namespace of their class, the intent here is different: to prevent unintentional overriding
of superclass private methods.*

Comment: Alright, this answer provides a good tip about Apple's reserved private method naming convention. It doesn't address the 1 vs 2 underscore difference though. I guess both 1 or 2 underscores such as in the sample output above indicate private Apple methods, but why 1 vs 2 underscores?